# Spring xd issue with http-client

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have spring xd module  with rabbitmq as a transport. My module  has http source http client processor which calls a rest url http://x.y.z/test

```
stream create --name cycletest4 --definition "http |  http-client --url='''https://x.y.z/test''' --httpMethod=GET | log" 

http post --data '{ "messageAttribute": { "channelType" : "EML", "contentKey" : "20020", "messageFormat" : "1", "contentSubscriber" : "dmttts", "languageCode" : "en-ca" }, "substitutionKeyValueData" : { "SvcgLOBCd": "CA", "User": "user", "phone": "yyyy, "accountLast": "tttt", "userName": "LP", "Company": "bbbb", "firstName": "Ryan" } }'
```

Now when my rest client throws any exception like 404 or connection time out exception and   the message is going back  the rabbit queue between http|http-client

My understanding was only connection time out exception will be put back queue and any other exception or 200 will move the message to next component it is http-client| log.But when i tried it all exception were put back the queue  between http|http-client.

Now my usecase was i want to retry all socket time /connection time out exception .any other  system exception  50x errors I want to write to   log or file sink?How can I achieve this.Basically depending on exception I want to route retry and non retry exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 2xx results will go to the `log`.

`4xx` and `5xx` are considered errors.

You will need a custom `http-client` module to trap the exceptions you consider 'ok' and forward them to the `output` channel. Something like...

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="input" ref="gw" />

<int:gateway request-channel="toHttp" error-channel="errors" />

<int:chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">
    <!-- examine payload.cause (http status code etc) and decide whether 
         to throw an exception or return the status code for sending to output -->
</int:chain>
```

Comment: Hi Gary we tried as below but  we faced issue stated below

Comment: Don't post clarification as another answer, edit your question instead. The problem is you are returning null to the gateway, it will wait forever for the reply. Add `default-reply-timeout="0"` to the gateway to release the thread after filtering.

Answer (score 0):

We tried implementing as suggested above. It is now filtering the 4XX errors and sending the  payload to the next module. However the messages are stuck unacknowledged in the internal rabbit mq. The acknowledgement is not happening in case of 2XX also after the change. Before the changes the 2XX acknowledgement was happening fine. The 5XX retry continue to happen just fine. Please let us know how to overcome this.

Here is the context xml

```
<service-activator input-channel="inputX" ref="gw" />

<gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toHttp" error-channel="errors" />

<beans:bean id="responseInterceptor" class="com.batch.httpclient.ResponseInterceptor">
</beans:bean>

<chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">
<transformer ref="responseInterceptor"  />
</chain>


<int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                           request-channel='toHttp' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
                           expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                           reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<beans:bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
            factory-method="outboundMapper">
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="*"/>
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
<channel id="inputX" />
<channel id="toHttp" />
```

And the Java code for ResponseInterceptor looks like this -

```
public Message<String> transform(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {


        if(null != errorMessage && null != errorMessage.getPayload() && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getCause()
                && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getCause().getMessage()){
            String rootCause = errorMessage.getPayload().getCause().getMessage();
            //check if the error message contains 400 or 404 http code.
            if(rootCause.contains("400") || rootCause.contains("404")){
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload(errorMessage.getPayload().getCause().getMessage())
                        .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getHeaders())
                        .removeHeader("errorChannel")
                        .removeHeader("replyChannel")
                        .setReplyChannelName("output").setErrorChannelName(null).build();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```